# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function in Wordpress custom template

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Im making a custom template in Wordpress. I used to install plugin *Post Carousel – Post Grid, Filter & Masonry for WordPress* and add a shortcode on page. But i constanlty get an error and as result js is broken and carousel not working. Shortcode works perfecly in Wordpress page builders.
Error:

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: jQuery(...).slick is not a function TypeError: jQuery(...).slick is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://test/magnetic-one-template-page/:274:37)
    at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30005)
    at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2:30307) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
t @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
c @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
B @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
```

Here is my scripts in head

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/css/code_test-style.css' ); ?>">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/71fcadc668.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css">
```

and before closing body tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to initialize slick first:

```
$('.your-slider').slick({
   infinite: true,
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

For more reference: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If the problem still occurs, try to wrap initialization in jquery document ready:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
       $('.your-slider').slick({
           infinite: true,
           slidesToShow: 3,
           slidesToScroll: 3
       });
    }); 
});
```

Also, try to move slick cdn to the header, it looks like .slick function unable to find a library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cross check** and avoid this 2 things

1. There not multiple versions of jQuery being loaded, if "Yes" use only **ONE**
2. Should not use jQuery **slim** version.